# React Router 4 / path-to-regexp multiple optional segments

Tags: express, react-router-v4

In React router 3 I could have path like this:

```
/root(/id/:id)(/di/:di)
```

That would match

```
/root
/root/id/1
/root/di/2
/root/id/1/di/2
```

Perfect.

I can't figure out how to do it in React Router 4. All examples are doing only one thing.

Using [Express Route tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) I can come up with a route like

```
/root/id/:id?/di/:di?
```

But that would match only

```
/root/id/1/di/2
```

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it in the end, it's a litte bit ridiculous but it works:

```
  <Route
    path="/root/:firstKey?/:firstId?/:secondKey?/:secondId?"
    render={({ match: { params: { firstKey, secondKey, firstId, secondId } } }) => {
      const params = { [firstKey]: firstId, [secondKey]: secondId }
      return (<Whatever {...params} />)
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 3):

In react router v4 you can enclose your regex inside `()`. So this regex should work and match all the paths you gave : `/root(/id/|/di/):id*(/id/|/di/)?:di*`. In the Express router Tester tool that you gave the link to, the keys wo**nt** show up with this regex but it does work, I tested on localhost and keys works just fine.

Note that I didn't use `?` after first capturing group, i.e., `(/id/|/di/)` because if I did then it would become optional and then path like `/root/12` would be matched too.

Comment: can you please elaborate how this work? I need to convert this path "entity((/:contextId)(/:contextRelType)/active(/:activeId)(/:activeRelType))"

Comment: @SergeyOrlov ReactRouter v4 uses path-to-regexp for matching paths, you can check out https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#parameter-modifiers for examples related to it. My example's purpose was to match all the cases that are given in the original question. The URL part inside brackets `()` is basically regex, for example this pattern `/hey(/jerry|/tom)` will match both paths `/hey/tom` and `/hey/jerry` whereas the `?` after it makes it optional.